# Convention badge, and how it pertains to moderator requirements after meta split

Tags: support, moderator-election, convention-badge

How does the meta split effect moderator requirements, specifically towards the [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention)?

[Moderator requirements from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5)

> For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the
>   election must have all of the following badges:
>
> - Civic Duty
> - Strunk & White
> - Deputy
> - Convention

[Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention)

> 10 posts with score of 2 on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Note the Convention badge meta requirement links to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't affect the existing badges at all: the folks who have them earned them fair and square, and they'll keep them. Until today, the site they earned those badges on *was* Stack Overflow's meta site.

[We just wrapped up one election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250068/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results), and probably won't be running another one until next year - by then, folks who don't already have them should've had ample opportunity to earn the necessary badges here, on this *new* meta site. So the description was correct, and will continue to be.

Comment: But my progress towards Convention is reset? You'd probably earn this badge before breakfast, but I'm not particularly active on meta, so my 3 posts with a score of 2+ didn't come quickly. Regardless, I was on my way to the badge...

Comment: Yeah, no good way around that I'm afraid.