# February 2014 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderator-resignation

Stack Overflow's [February 2014 moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) has come to a close, sacrifices have been made [at the altar of STV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english), and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: bohemian] [image: 0x7fffffff] [image: bluefeet]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6524971895488512/0).

We're all very fortunate that so many skilled, dedicated individuals decided to volunteer their time this year - while we could only make 3 of them moderators, I think it's safe to say that *many* of the other candidates are exemplary of the talent and conduct that makes this community awesome. Please join me in thanking them all for their hard work and willingness to help others!

---

Also, I'd like to wish a fond farewell to two veteran moderators who are stepping down this year:

**[The jjnguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598/jjnguy)** and  **[NullUserException](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception)** have both served since [November of 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2).  These two have each done a lot for Stack Overflow over the years, both as moderators and as trusted members of the community - please join me in thanking them for their service and wishing them all the best in their next adventure.

Comment: Funny how none of the moderators serving as a face for the community have their picture in their avatar, and only one has disclosed their real name. [Online disinhibition effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_disinhibition_effect#Popular_culture)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu - Actually all the 3 have disclosed their real name. Bohemian did after winning the election but the other two had given it out in their election campaign nomination itself.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It's all in the elections page that's linked in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/election/5

Comment: @DanDascalescu - I don't have my face as my avatar, in fact only four of the existing moderators have their face as their avatar. It's not an issue.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - The link you provided demonstrates at least one reason why a user on a site like this might not want to reveal their identity. The person who asked that question did so to specifically harass a particular moderator, even going so far as to find their real name later and start employing personal attacks against them outside of this site. Other users have been harassed based on their gender on other sites, and so choose to use a pseudonym. It is their right to do so, and moderators can be held accountable for their actions without public disclosure of their real name.

Answer (score 183):

In case anyone is curious, if there had been 4, 5 or 6 seats the following candidates would have been elected, too:

- [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) (4 seats)
- [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout) (5 seats)
- [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) (6 seats)

---

For those who prefer a text-based report, here it is:

```
Loading ballots from file stackoverflow-com-2014-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 21571 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 21571 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Stack Overflow Moderator Election 2014 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|Undo         |bluefeet     |0x7fffffff   |Bohemian     |Jon Clements |Doorknob     |Raghav Sood  
  |             |             |             |             |             |             |             
  |-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
  |Siddharth Rou|Matt         |meagar       |Exhausted    |Surplus      |Threshold    
  |t            |             |             |             |             |             
====================================================================================================
 1|  1379.000000|  3372.000000|  1951.000000|  5707.000000|  1545.000000|  1181.000000|  1375.000000
  |  1749.000000|  1389.000000|  1923.000000|     0.000000|   314.249999|  5392.750001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Bohemian has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 2|  1394.197388|  3463.184328|  1984.037800|  5392.755459|  1568.622027|  1202.254318|  1394.492302
  |  1778.899209|  1412.236586|  1970.629495|     9.691088|     2.428230|  5390.327229
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Bohemian, 0.944937.
====================================================================================================
 3|  1518.280916|  3604.699494|  2156.608029|  5543.000442|  1656.925807|             |  1489.355578
  |  1889.817548|  1536.650492|  2099.364913|    76.296781|   169.324637|  5373.675805
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Doorknob and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 4|  1527.864096|  3654.866864|  2176.322824|  5373.678352|  1671.040792|             |  1501.074768
  |  1907.021088|  1550.621152|  2126.815528|    81.694536|     1.351985|  5372.326367
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Bohemian, 0.916072.
====================================================================================================
 5|  1650.640856|  3838.672168|  2342.708488|  5610.024928|  1796.817552|             |             
  |  2229.413888|  1663.985408|  2272.040472|   166.696240|   258.948987|  5351.075941
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Raghav Sood and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 6|  1666.581924|  3916.094172|  2375.309452|  5351.077712|  1819.397208|             |             
  |  2258.843552|  1686.649632|  2316.396388|   180.649960|     3.490201|  5347.587511
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Bohemian, 0.873788.
====================================================================================================
 7|             |  4169.705676|  2697.396716|  5587.000472|  1954.435992|             |             
  |  2400.260972|  1884.202960|  2500.105016|   377.892196|   288.723520|  5298.276952
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Undo and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 8|             |  4256.538741|  2735.462381|  5298.279402|  1979.993722|             |             
  |  2433.269277|  1910.392860|  2550.588306|   406.475311|     7.148229|  5291.131173
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Bohemian, 0.828633.
====================================================================================================
 9|             |  4539.645084|  3030.399512|  5580.014622|  2167.618476|             |             
  |  2638.065398|             |  2820.067740|   795.189168|   386.061913|  5193.952709
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Matt and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
10|             |  4877.664666|  3334.651175|  5921.411418|             |             |             
  |  2891.375620|             |  3155.345450|  1390.551671|   876.299335|  5045.112083
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Jon Clements and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
====================================================================================================
11|             |  5147.198812|  3460.343850|  5045.118876|             |             |             
  |  2996.834840|             |  3320.891900|  1600.611722|   207.123548|  4992.597070
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Bohemian, 0.706006. Candidate bluefeet has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
12|             |  5563.531846|  3920.327034|  5485.666620|             |             |             
  |             |             |  3700.641150|  2900.833350|  1714.115140|  4667.541663
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Siddharth Rout and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
====================================================================================================
13|             |  4875.924090|  4152.023931|  4801.633837|             |             |             
  |             |             |  4036.952149|  3704.465993|   744.290923|  4466.633502
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: bluefeet, 0.838953 and Bohemian, 0.600714.
====================================================================================================
14|             |  4542.618712|  4250.793395|  4521.180363|             |             |             
  |             |             |  4186.980201|  4069.427329|   313.012739|  4375.393168
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: bluefeet, 0.768531 and Bohemian, 0.558804.
====================================================================================================
15|             |  4406.860299|  4292.300694|  4396.604975|             |             |             
  |             |             |  4250.832600|  4224.401432|   130.165988|  4336.649643
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: bluefeet, 0.740240 and Bohemian, 0.540786.
====================================================================================================
16|             |  4349.324729|  4309.505375|  4345.372825|             |             |             
  |             |             |  4277.494205|  4289.302866|    53.848986|  4320.424284
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: bluefeet, 0.728447 and Bohemian, 0.533412.
====================================================================================================
17|             |  4325.653432|  4316.621565|  4323.986348|             |             |             
  |             |             |  4288.544631|  4316.194024|    25.156860|  4313.701495
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: bluefeet, 0.723607 and Bohemian, 0.530350. Candidate 0x7fffffff has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.

Winners are bluefeet, 0x7fffffff, and Bohemian.
```

Comment: Rats, I wish there had been 5 seats!

Comment: So do I... so do I :p

Comment: Where are fancy tables and beautiful graphs? :( (Yeah, I know the election ended less than 1 hour ago, but well... :p)

Comment: @MaximeLorant here: http://www.opavote.org/results/6524971895488512/0

Comment: Hmm? Wasn't Matt eliminated before Jon Clements? Why would Matt have gotten a 6th seat?

Comment: You ... *eliminated* the losing candidates? Oh dear.

Comment: Oh no, don't worry @AmalMurali. They are on a farm now. They're fine.

Comment: @Wooble: I think the thresholds somehow change depending on the number of seats.

Comment: Why are there only 3 seats available? With the amount of work the moderators have to do, and the amount of quality candidates, why not accept 6 new moderators?

Comment: @AmalMurali -  they knew too much...

Comment: @3dgoo Training new mods requires SE/existing mod involvement, you can't have too many new mods at once

Comment: What only 3 Seats? Hmph! I was told there will be 6 seats! All that bribe goes in vain? :p Congrats@All New Mods :)

Comment: This post is not mobile friendly.

Comment: 0x7fffffff won over Exhausted just by the skin of his teeth!

Comment: Voted for Matt, I'm really hoping he'll get the seat eventually.

Comment: Minneapolis uses this sort of 1st through third choice election. However it takes them a few weeks to declare a winner meanwhile SO is the second after the election closes. How sad...

Comment: It says no candidates withdrew. Does that *not* include those that just left SO during elections, deleting their SO-login on the way out the door? Or would they have had to withdraw first? Or was this just a top-10 thing? Just curious.

Comment: Congrats to the new mods:)
P.S. @SiddharthRout I wanted to have an Indian Presence on SO. Too bad

Comment: @WhozCraig: Candidates who withdrew don't even end up in the ballot file - it only shows the ten people who have been in the election.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I sorta figured. It was the "No candidates have withdrawn." that caught my attention. I'm probably not reading the relevance of that as it pertains to posted results correctly, which would be my bad I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @NickLarsen Assuming you mean the text-report, it is also not very desktop friendly :-)

Comment: @Wooble Second and Third choices get in play after candidates are eliminated and there are excess votes on those reaching the threshold. If there were 6 seats, the threshold would be different and Matt would had been elected earlier.

Comment: Congrates to all Moderators :) Voted for Bohemian, Bluefeet and 1 from @Sidhartha/@Raghav ;). Hope 1 from you two guys will be MOderator next year.

Comment: The number of exhausted votes by the time we get the third person elected suggests to me that with this number of candidates we need to provide more preferences.

Comment: @WhozCraig, In a hand counted election, it is normal for candidates with no hope of winning to withdraw after the first round of counting so as to speed up the process.    Also sometimes candidates withdraw because they have been elected to anther post, e.g. they have won the student union president, so withdraw from the exec election.

Comment: @IanRingrose "it is normal for candidates with no hope of winning to withdraw ". Ok, but I never asked *why* someone withdrew. I simply wondered *how* "No candidates have withdrawn." appears in an election result where candidate(s) have not only withdrawn, but have left SO-outright. From what I've now seen, that proclamation on the results it meaningless (something I'm innately sensitive to on election results), so now my question is as well. Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig, the vote counting software is used by lots of people for different elections.  The "vote counting log" just shows what the counting software did with the data it was given.  It tells you nothing about what happened before or after the count.

Comment: @IanRingrose *exactly*,  As I said to ThieMaster, I get it. Its a process thing.I totally understand it now. How the software is *used* here renders that stat meaningless (and likewise my question); not inaccurate. Its all good. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 149):

First of all, congratulations to the newly elected mods!

Unfortunately I had much, much less free time than I had anticipated when I volunteered for the position. Out with old, and in with the new!

Even though I wasn't able to effect as much change as I originally hoped I could, I am glad. I am glad I was able to contribute towards improving the site. I am glad for the nice experience these two years or so have been.

Thanks, and Godspeed to the new mods!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I, and I'm sure the community, will remember you very positively for it!

Comment: As someone who mostly participated alongside you both before and during our mod terms I'm glad that we shared the experience. Godspeed to you too!

Answer (score 42):

For everybody requesting Bohemian to reveal his real name: He did keep up his promise. He said he would reveal his real name if he was elected and he did. Its now visible on [his profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian).

Join me in welcoming the 3 new moderators, [*Glen Edmonds* (Bohemian)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian), [*Taryn* (bluefeet)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) and [*Mick* (0x7fffffff)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff).

Now we can only hope that they put up their real pictures too(no compulsion), but that can be left to their own wish :)

Comment: I really don't understand, why would we even *hope* to see them user their real names/photos? A lot of people seem to be asking for this, and I don't understand why it would be desirable in any way. Most of our current moderators don't user their real names/photos, and there is nothing at all compelling them to do so.

Comment: if I ever nominate, my campaign promise will likely be _not_ to reveal my real name

Comment: @meagar - I just mentioned that Bohemian kept his promise and revealed his name. Nobody had compelled him or for that matter anybody to reveal their real names. And regarding their real pictures, I made it clear that it I'm just hoping to see(again no compulsion) and that it is upto their wish. I really doubt that having a small silly hope from your newly elected moderators is that bad. There was never any compulsion in anything(atleast from my side).

Comment: @gnat - Opinions vary. Also nobody can compel you to *reveal* your real name. Bohemian did it out of his own wish and I just happened to highlight it seeing so many comments/requests from other users regarding it.

Comment: @meagar: Because humans are creepy like that.

Comment: @BoltClock - But unicorns aren't and that's why you love them :)

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: Exactly ;) I don't love you humans though. Creeps.

Comment: @meagar: Some people feel more comfortable about the core people of a community with real names and pictures (including me). It is similar to when you introduce yourself in real life, at least to me. It gives more confidence. Sure, it is not necessary to do the "job", but this site is about community, at least to me, not just some people doing their job separately from others. But yes, Bohemian also wished to do it himself based on the nomination description, so I think it is all fine, and it is also done now.

Comment: When one is modded, one wants to see the face of one's moderator...

Hmmmm... That's a nice tagline. I think I've just come up with an idea for a movie script....

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn get's his SE checks written to Mr. Unicorn. Never had one problem cashing them in.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ it doesn't matter whether promise is one way or another, real magic seems to happen when someone mentions _real name_ - this triggers emotional response and involvement, as evidenced by megazillion comments and 5 or 10 deleted answers here, all of which say the same: _wow, Bohemian, real name_

Comment: Now that was an anti-climax!

Comment: @meagar how do we know that they're not robots?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO We don't, and that's kind of the point. They might be robots for all we know, but so long as they're excellent moderators, nobody should know or care.  You know, besides the whole "OH MY GOD SENTIENT ROBOTS" thing.

Comment: @meagar: Because it's 2014, we're not script kiddies hiding behind lolcat avatars, and with power comes responsibility? Studies even show that when someone (i.e. our users) feels "watched", [they are likely to behave more honestly](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/notrocketscience/2008/05/10/how-big-brother-keeps-us-honest/). And conversely, [people tend to behave more responsibly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_disinhibition_effect) when their [real names are known](http://weis2013.econinfosec.org/papers/ChoWEIS2013.pdf).

Comment: congratulate to new moderator...

Comment: @DanDascalescu Disregarding your rather asinine association with aliases and "script kiddies", how does a moderator use their real name make our users feel more watched? And for real names making for more responsible behaviour, we do not have a problem with moderators behaving irresponsibly, so that's entirely moot.

Comment: @DanDascalescu No, we really don't, and your link isn't in any way an indication that we do.

Comment: @meagar: I've updated my comment with more links. Maybe moderators among themselves don't have a problem, but the [community clearly has a problem](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow/document_view) with [moderators](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/).

Comment: @DanDascalescu No, a very small number of members of the community have a problem with with moderators. The vast, vast majority of the community never interacts with them directly.

Comment: @meagar: you can think whatever you want but most professional people I met that do actually interact with stackoverflow actually complains **a lot** about things are going on, a lot of people are looking for a different place because all people making important/interesting questions find everything closed. And yes we are still on stackoverflow because we can't find a good alternative right now. I've been a member for years and the website is **not** becoming better. The greatest questions and answers are usually from old questions **which now are closed!!!**

Comment: @meagar: Here's a fantastic example of how StackOverflow stopped letting users create extremely valuable content - a [question with 2874 stars and 857 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) that was closed as _"not a good question"_. How much ad revenue does that bring to SE? If money doesn't matter, how about the sheer value of the content in that question and its answers, which can never be updated? What if Git appeared after SO tightened its rules to extremes? What about the next Git? SO won't be a place to discuss it.

Comment: @DanDascalescu That question isn't a question, it doesn't fit he QA format, and it should have been closed. There is literally an entire Internet where that kind of content can be hosted. It doesn't belong here. Stack Overflow is not a blogging platform. It cannot be all things to all people. It is successful because it contains carefully curated content and *rejects* things that don't belong, rather than becoming a dumping ground for anything programming-related. Yes, lots of people liked that question. Lots of people like cat pictures, doesn't mean we should become the next Reddit.

Answer (score 17):

I am happy to see [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) on that list. He is a very active member and has a huge reputation.

I am a little disappointed as there are no Indians on the list.

Anyway, good luck to all the moderators for the new role and I hope the new moderators will take some steps to prevent the straight downvotes for the newbie joins Stack Overflow.

Straight downvoting of new members should be prevented as to give them inspiration. They should be made aware regarding the quality of questions, the tags, etc...

Comment: It doesn't really matter where someone is from (india, europe, US, mars, whatever) as long as he's a good moderator...

Comment: @ThiefMaster It does matter because of time inconsistency between different countries, Typically at this time most developers are from india, so it does matter

Comment: @Aღmirkhan i dont think so either  ....  programmers do not sleep (may be they take nap :)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I am a programmer & i sleep at night :P

Comment: What exactly would Indians bring that other cultures don't? Also down votes are given due to the quality of the question, not because people are new.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I don't want new people picked on. But it seems to be quite a misconception that moderators are there to hold the hands of new people. The people who are best equipped to deal with new people are the new people themselves - all the instructions and guidance is in place, they just have to read it and follow it. Unfortunately a good proportion of them don't, they would rather spew out a low quality question, grab the free answers and run and have no interest in contributing to the site in a positive way.

Comment: Then the regular members get the blame for being all scary and down voting them. You have to remember that down voting is not for punishing people, its for indicating quality. If the quality sucks and it can't be (or shouldn't be) fixed then.... why let it slide?

Comment: Having huge reputation is a non-argument in this discussion.

Comment: How does having huge reputation have anything to do with mod duties? After reaching 20k, you don't unlock any more privileges

Comment: I voted for Doorknob and Undo, mainly because they **didn't** have huge reputation.  Huge reputation says to me that they hawk posts and make it impossible for the noobs to get rep.  That's not a good moderator, IMO.

Comment: I did not meant that good reputations is useful for good mod, i just praised Bohemian for having such a nice reputation, to get such nice reputation shows that how much time is he spending on Stack overflow @JohnnyBones

Comment: I am just curious, why @Bohemian when you are from Australia and not from Bohemia?

Comment: @slugster I still consider myself newbie and I feel downvoting as strong negativism. I understand it when pupil asks us to do his homework. But if person is just rookie then his question may look stupid but he needs to get direction, not kick into his ?ss. I would be happy if moderators could take it into consideration in their job.

Comment: Time zone is irrelevant, there are many other countries near the Indian timezone too.