# When will the election results be declared?

Tags: support, moderator-election

How long after the election ends will the results be declared? Is there any specific date for that? I checked the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) but it does not say. I searched about it but didn't find an answer.

Comment: Last year Shog9 [declared the result within 1 minute of the elections closing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250068/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results). I guess he had the post prepared, ran the OpenSTV processor on the votes and filled in the userids in his post. Presto!

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I would call SO quality :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Or, it was rigged. *Dun dun dunnn!*

Comment: @Boann: I'll go and investigate! With a big suitcase with investigation manuals, totally not piles of money to give to Shog9!

Comment: I wonder if Shog has/had access to the results before the election ended. E.g. he could see that Martijn was across the threshold 10 minutes before voting ended and no one else was even close.

Comment: lol.. I asked this question before election result declared. And now it is marked as duplicate after result declared with result page. :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It will be declared within hours (if not minutes) of being finished.

Comment: Ohh to fast. it's nice.

Comment: @ketan I would more say like: *6 - 8 weeks* :)

Comment: @Rizier123 as per oded within hours. Is this wrong?

Comment: @ketan It's an [old joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1288).

Comment: Hmm, how can we be sure that there's no e-rigging?

Comment: @Rizier123 did you mean six to eight minutes?

Comment: @JanDvorak No, weeks are correct :D

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, The election results have been downloadable in the past. There is no reason to believe that wouldn't be the case now either.

Comment: @Andy And how do we know the data offered for download is a faithful representation of the votes cast?  There may be interesting uses for the data, but auditing is not one of them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, I have no answer to that question. If you are concerned, I suggest you post another Meta question and ask for more details.

Comment: within minutes of the election closing I would expect the results to be here: [download results election 6](http://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/6) you can replay that through [the STV tool](http://www.openstv.org/) to get the resutls before htey are official. (It used to be free, but apparently OpenSTV is not so free any more?)